# Looking for inspiration/module meant for guiding customers step-by-step

Tags: magento2, module

I'm looking for a module, or inspiration for creating a module that can do the following:

I would like to create a page inside my Magento 2 store which is named "Wizard". This Wizard can guide customers through a step-by-step process into finding exactly what it is after at the end of the process.

What do I need to go forth? Is there a module I can use for inspiration or any other source?

Example of what I am after - https://mkfresh.pl/front/wizard/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about a series of CMS pages which build a layered navigation query?

The intermediate button would take you to the next CMS page in the series.

The final button would take you to the product collection with all the filters applied.

`http://domain.com/category/subcategory?brand=100&color=6`

No need for plugins.  With a bit of effort you could create some really clean URLs.

The only thing I will say is that it could be a challenge to manage.  Say you've got three levels with three options each.  3 x 3 means you've got 9 CMS pages.